# error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element' when deploy cloud functions firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm building an Angular + Firebase web app and due to some complex queries I started looking for Cloud Functions from firebase.

My project looks like:

```
MyProject
   |__ node_modules
   |__ src (with app and my complete project)
   |__ some files like tsconfig.json
```

I followed the classic tutorial: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started

```
MyProject
   |__ node_modules
   |__ src (with app and my complete project)
   |__ some files like tsconfig.json
   |__ functions
           |__ node_modules
           |__ src
```

But problem when using firebase deploy --only functions:

```
i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "%RESOURCE_DIR%" run lint

> functions@ lint E:\Travail\wamp64\www\WhoAmI\WhoAmI\functions
> tslint --project tsconfig.json

Running command: npm --prefix "%RESOURCE_DIR%" run build

> functions@ build E:\Travail\wamp64\www\WhoAmI\WhoAmI\functions
> tsc

../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(191,29): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'XMLHttpRequest'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(512,41): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Event'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(517,20): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(527,21): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(552,20): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Event'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(562,20): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(582,13): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(944,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(952,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(960,20): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(999,36): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Document'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(1046,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(1054,19): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(1061,19): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(1070,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(1078,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(1087,20): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(1096,20): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(1105,20): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(1114,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(1191,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(1191,45): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(1309,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Window'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(1316,20): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Node'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(1378,29): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'XMLDocument'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(1402,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(1412,39): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HTMLElement'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(1422,39): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Document'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(1437,70): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'XMLHttpRequest'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(1472,69): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'XMLHttpRequest'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(1482,115): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'XMLHttpRequest'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(3075,14): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(3119,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(3119,42): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'DocumentFragment'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(3119,59): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Text'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(3126,57): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(3135,35): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(3135,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'DocumentFragment'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(3135,60): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Text'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(3142,58): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(3150,35): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(3159,35): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(3159,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'DocumentFragment'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(3159,60): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Text'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(3166,58): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(3197,38): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(3197,46): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Text'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(3205,39): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(3205,47): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Text'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(3214,36): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(3214,44): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'DocumentFragment'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(3214,61): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Text'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(3221,59): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(3229,36): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(3245,37): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(3253,42): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(3253,50): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Text'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(3260,29): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(3287,16): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HTMLElement'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(3301,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(3316,37): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(3331,39): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(3346,38): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(3354,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HTMLElement'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(3360,12): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HTMLElement'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(3373,35): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(3386,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HTMLElement'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(3395,37): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(3402,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(3440,41): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(3454,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(3463,39): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(3498,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(3505,21): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(3527,19): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(3555,20): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(3570,39): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(3598,47): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(3631,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(3654,40): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(3661,19): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(3661,27): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(3707,28): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(3748,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! functions@ build: `tsc`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Any idea ? Did I do something wrong ?

Versions:
"firebase": "^5.0.4"
"firebase-functions": "^2.0.3"
"firebase-admin": "~6.0.0"
firebase CLI: 4.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your angular project and your functions project should be in different folders.  Right now you have them combined together, and the Firebase CLI is trying to lint and deploy your web code to Cloud Functions, which is not going to work.

Separate your two node projects completely with no overlap between them, because they operate independently of each other:

```
MyProject
  /angular
    /src
    /node_modules
  /functions
    /src
    /node_modules
```

Comment: I first try to just create a folder functions and initiate under this one everything → not working. Then I add angular folder and move my angular project under this folder and initiate again under /functions → working ! Thank's again Doug for taking some of your time to help me ! Let's try this cloud functions (-: